# Uso de función Lambda en Python

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, pyspark

Tengo la siguiente función en Python:

```
def carta(lista):
    a = ''
    for i in lista:
        if(i[:2] == 'CC') & ((i[-3:] != 'CC/')):
            a = i
    return a
```

El cual me regresaba el valor de `i` si y solo si algún elemento de mi lista empezaba con `'CC'` pero diferente de `'CC/'`.

Sin embargo en el ambiente de producción en el que estoy, no están permitidas las funciones (udf), por lo cual estoy tratando de modificar ese código usando lambdas de la siguiente manera:

```
carta_lambda = lambda lista : ('CC' in lista [:2]) + lista and ('CC/' not in lista [-3:]) + lista
```

Sin embargo esto me regresa un enmascaramiento booleano de cada elemento, es decir un `True` o `False` no el valor `i` del elemento de la lista.

A manera de ejemplo, si tengo lo siguiente:

```
[CC845, RF456, BG838]
```

me regresa un `True`

Y si tengo algo como esto:

```
[RF456, JP654, BG838]
```

me regresa un `False`

Sin embargo de la primer lista yo esperaría como salida un `'CC845'` y para la segunda salida un `0`.

¿Alguna idea de como podría implementar esto con lambdas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este lambda te retorna una arreglo con los elementos que cumplen la condición:

```
f = lambda lista : [x for x in lista if x[:2] == "CC" and x[3] != "/"]
```

La parte `x for x in lista` recorre toda la lista, pero sólo se selección los elementos que cumplan la condición `if x[:2] == "CC" and x[3] != "/"`.

**Demo**

```
a = ['CC845', 'RF456', 'BG838']
print(f(a))
```

produce:

```
['CC845']
```

Comment: Me sirvio mucho, mil gracias Candid

Answer (score 1):

`carta` tambien se puede convertir a un lambda usando `filter` y `next`

```
carta2 = lambda lista: next(filter(lambda cod: cod[:2] == 'CC'
                                               and cod[-3:] != 'CC/', lista), "")
```

`filter` lo que hace es devolver un iterable con los elementos de otro iterable que
cumplan una condición (dada por un lambda). Luego con `next` se toma un elemento del
iterable devuelto por `filter`. Si ese iterable se encuentra vacio devuelve por
defecto `""`.